# How to copy data from one instance to another in aws lightsail without copy snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have error `sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`
So unable to use sudo commands so i want copy data to new instance.I have tried with create instance from snapshot but getting same error in new instance.how can i do without lost data.

Comment: you can copy using `scp` if you have `ssh` connectivity between the two instances.

Comment: @Marcin using scp how can  you answer?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There are many examples on how to use `scp` to copy files from one server to the other, e.g. [here](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)

Comment: thanks @Marcin let me try

Comment: No problem. Let me know if it works. If so, I can provide an answer for future reference.

Comment: @Marcin getting error while use scp Permission denied (publickey).lost connection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216937/discussion-between-bhavesh-chauhan-and-marcin).